# Horizontal scroll event not working on IE? (seems like no other event is working)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, internet-explorer-11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #myDIV {
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
#content {
        height: 800px;
        width: 2000px;
        background-color: coral;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Scroll inside the div element to display the number of pixels the content of div is scrolled horizontally and vertically.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
    <div id="content">Scroll inside me!</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        alert("scroll");
    });
    document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        alert("click");
    });

</script>
```

Why its not working in **IE** I played this same code in w3 try it yourself page, it works in **IE** but not if I tried it as a separate file, so confused. Even if some one downvote this please tell me what I am missing?

I found these things when I browse other answers:

- pointing to window.scroll but I need on a particular element
- Use overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; or vice versa.(which didn't work and also I need scroll on both ways)

NOTE:

> This code works clearly in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad. May be helpful for someone like me, Please enable scripting in your IE. :_(

> A thing to note here is, Although script is not enabled it w3 school exercises exercises worked because of iframe?. If so how?